# implementing server for licencing management

Tags: c++, client-server, communication

I would like to implement the server side of a licence management software. I use C++ in LINUX OS.

When the software starts it must connect to a server that checks privileges and allows/disallow running of some features.

My question is about the implementation of the communication between client and server across internet:

The server will have a static IP on internet so is it enough to use a simple TCP/IP socket client that will connect to a TCP/IP socket server ( providing IP/PORT) ?

I am familiar with socket communication , but less with communication across internet so my question is whether this is the right approach or do I need to use a different mechanism like a http client server or other.

Regards

AFG

Comment: iptables DNAT is so simple, hardcoded IP will not help you. Use TLS and getaddrinfo(). If you can, use some framework with encryption support.

Comment: @Pihhan.Thanks! Very useful ! Do you think that TLS ver 1 is enough or is better to look at higher version of TLS? I found a library called openssl but they have TLS v1. Do you know some linux library for higher TLS that people use in the business (possibly free)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some benefits to using HTTP as a transport:

- **easier to get right, more likely to work in production**: Yes, you will probably have to add additional dependencies to deal with HTTP (client and server side), but it's still preferable to yet another homegrown protocol, which you have to implement, maintain, care about backwards compatibility, deal with multiplatform issues (eg. endianness), etc.  In terms of implementation ease, using an HTTP based solution should be far easier in the common case (especially true if you build a REST style service API for license checking).
- **More help available**: HTTP as the foundation of the web is one of the most widely used technologies today.  Most (all?) problems you will run into are probably publicly documented with solutions/workarounds.
- **Encryption 'for free'**: Encryption is already a solved problem (HTTPS/SSL), both with regard to transport as well as with regard to what you have to implement on your end, and it's just a matter of setting it up.
- **Server Authentication 'for free'**: HTTPS/SSL doesn't only solve encryption but also server authentication, so that the client can verify whether it's actually talking to the right service.
- **Guaranteed to work on the internet**: HTTP/HTTPS traffic is common on the internet, so you won't run into routing problems or firewalls which are hard to traverse.  This might be a problem when using your own protocol.
- **Flexibility out of the box**: You also put less constraints on clients communicating with your server, as it's very simple to build a client in many different environments, as long as they can talk HTTP (and maybe SSL), and they know how to issue the request to your server (ie. what your service API looks like).
- **Easy to integrate with administrative webapp**: If you want to allow users to manage their accounts associated with licenses in some way (update contact info etc.), then you might even combine the license server with that application.  You can also build the license administration UI part into the same app if that's useful.

And as a last remark (this puts additional constraints on your client side HTTPS/SSL implementation): you can even use client side SSL certificates, which essentially allow authenticating the client to the server.  Depending on how you use them, client side certificates are harder to manage, but they can be eg. expired, or revoked, so to some extent they actually *are* licenses (to connect to the server).

Comment: SSL is totally unrelated to HTTP. You don't get any more SSL with HTTP than you get without HTTP. In fact you probably get more security without HTTP, because when you use SSL directly, you'll have to understand it at least a bit and thus stand a better chance of not doing some stupid mistake. Most HTTP libraries present their SSL options in notoriously confusing ways.

Comment: @unthough! Thanks for the explanation that I like a lot..a sort of very good PRO/CONS on these usages!

Comment: @JanHudec I agree that HTTP over SSL involves two distinct technologies, but from the perspective of someone building an app it's more useful to consider the combination of them as a single option because it's so common and often transparent to the server app.  It's by no means the only solution, and implementing a custom socket protocol over SSL/TLS could be a better fit depending on requirements, but I'd default to something proven, well-understood, easy-to-debug, easy-to-teach (write a spec for the custom socket proto?), etc. unless I have proof that it doesn't work for my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

- HTTP is not a different mechanism. It is a protocol operated over TCP/IP connections.
- Internet uses IP transport exclusively. You can use UDP, TCP or SCTP session (well, UDP is not much of a session) layer on top of it. TCP is the general choice.
- Sockets are operating system interface. They are the only interface to network in most systems, but some systems have different interface. Nothing to do with the transport itself.
- IP addresses are in practice tied to network topology, so I strongly discourage hardcoding the IP address into the server. If you have to change network provider for any reason, you won't be getting the same IP address. Use DNS, it's just one `gethostbyname` call.
- And don't forget to authenticate the server; even with hardcoded IP it's too easy to redirect it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me recap waht you are saying: both options are fine? OPTION 1. the client can use some kind of HTTPClient and the web server can use some PHP script(or other) to respond the client. OPTION 2. straight socket communication using a hostname/DNS?

Comment: Yes, both are fine. As are various middle options like using SSL/TLS alone with custom protocol.